# Combinatorics - problem about objects in a row

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> Suppose I have $X$ red balls (indistinguishable from each other), $Y$ blue balls (indistinguishable from each other) and $Z$ green balls (indistinguishable from each other).
>
> How many ways can I put them in a row?

If we were talking about only one of each ball would be simple because we would have 6 ways.

($RBG ,RGB, BRG, BGR ,GRB , GBR$)

How can I find a more general way for $X,Y,Z>1$??

Comment: Hi! Google *permutations with repetition* and you will find good explanations, tutorials and videos on this problem.

Comment: See [permutations of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It the balls were distinguishable then there would be $(X+Y+Z)!$ possibilities

but the red balls being indistinguishable means this is a factor of $X!$ too high

and the blue balls being indistinguishable means this is a factor of $Y!$ too high

and the green balls being indistinguishable means this is a factor of $Z!$ too high

so $\dfrac{(X+Y+Z)!}{X!Y!Z!}$ possibilities